# How to change the file icons ( projects icons) listed on the files tab in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, icons

I was wondering if there is a way to change the icons of the files listed in the files tab of IDE?

I often have same class names open simultaneously in my editor and would like to be able to diffrenciate between then by assigning different icons to different projects

[image: icons]

Answer (score 1):

From what I know these icons are provided by the plugin which implements the editor (in the org.eclipse.ui.editors extension point). From what I read [here](http://prasi82.blogspot.co.il/2010/10/eclipse-change-editor-icon.html), you can support changing the editor's icon at run time, but this would require the plugin to support this, and possibly most plugins don't.